# How to configure Android webview

Tags: java, android, android-studio, view, webview

I have a `WebView` in my Android application. The page that I'm opening has a hidden menu that cannot be seen.

```
webView = (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.webView);
WebSettings ws = webView.getSettings();
webView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(true);
ws.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
ws.setSupportZoom(false);

webView.setWebViewClient(new MyAppWebViewClient());
webView.loadUrl(DAFAULT_URL);
```